# windows service does not start to the scheduled time

Tags: c#, .net, magento, windows-services, poller

I have a windows service that communicates with the Magento API to extract the data. The windows service how ever when started for the first time runs properly without any error or problem. 
There is poller incorporated which calculates the next time to execution of the windows service and the key value "pollerExecutionTime" is specified in the config file. What I have noticed is that the windows service does not start at the scheduled time in spite of setting it to automatic start type.
Here is the code for the poller. If anyone can have a look and tell me what I am doing wrong it would be very helpful as I am not well versed in debugging windows services.

```
private DateTime _nextExecutionTime;

    public DateTime NextExecutionTime
    {
        get { 

            //if(_nextExecutionTime!=null)
            //    return _nextExecutionTime;

            return _nextExecutionTime = GetNextExecutionTime(Convert.ToDateTime(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pollerExecutionTime"]).TimeOfDay, DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).DayOfWeek); 
        }
        set { 

            _nextExecutionTime = value; 
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        DebugMode();

        try
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);

            if (!StartService())
            {
                Stop();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _logEntryError.Message = "OnStart: Cannot start the service due the following reason " + exception.Message + Environment.NewLine + exception.InnerException + Environment.NewLine + exception.StackTrace;

            Logger.Write(_logEntryError);
        }

        //StartService();
    }

    private bool StartService()
    {
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
        _timer.Interval = 10000; //First time after 10 sec
        _timer.Enabled = true;
        _timer.AutoReset = true;

        _logEntryStart.Message = "Execution of  CheckLongtimePendingRequestsAndDelegate Method -- STARTED";

        _logEntryEnd.Message = "Execution of  CheckLongtimePendingRequestsAndDelegate Method -- ENDED";

        return true;
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {

    }

    [Conditional("DEBUG_SERVICE")]
    private static void DebugMode()
    {
        Debugger.Break();
    }


    private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
       TimeSpan difference = NextExecutionTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now.Date);

       _timer.Interval = difference.TotalMilliseconds;

        try
        {
            Logger.Write(_logEntryStart);

            _svc.GetOrderList();
            _svc.GetCustomerList();
            _svc.GetInvoiceList();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _logEntryError.Message = "Error by invoking the WebMethods Method : " + exception.Message + Environment.NewLine + exception.InnerException + Environment.NewLine + exception.StackTrace;

            Logger.Write(_logEntryError);
        }

    }
    public static DateTime GetNextExecutionTime(TimeSpan time, DayOfWeek targetDayOfWeek)
    {
        var date = new DateTime(
            DateTime.Now.Year,
            DateTime.Now.Month,
            DateTime.Now.Day,
            time.Hours,
            time.Minutes,
            time.Seconds).AddDays(GetDaysToNextWeekDay(DateTime.Now,  targetDayOfWeek));

        return date;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the days to next week day.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="startDate">The start date.</param>
    /// <param name="targetDayOfWeek">The target day of week.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    /// <remarks></remarks>
    public static int GetDaysToNextWeekDay(DateTime startDate, DayOfWeek      targetDayOfWeek)
    {
        int start = (int)startDate.DayOfWeek;
        int target = (int)targetDayOfWeek;

        if (target <= start)
            target += 7;

        return target - start;
    }
```

Comment: The automatic start type is just for when the computer starts.  You are fighting against yourself here.  Don't stop the service, just let it sleep until it has to do something again.

Comment: But it does not start again when it supposed to run the next day at the specified time.

Comment: Check your logic for calculating your next interval.  If you are setting _timer.Interval to something less than 0 in , it will error out before you do anything.  Suggest NOT resetting the time interval.  Just let the timer poll at a regular interval and only DO something if the proper time has elapsed.